# opencl max work group size

Tags: size, opencl, wavefront, workgroup

Opencl defines maximum work group size.
What is the reason for that ?- is that harware limitation or just software design?
Why can`t I use any work group size ? - any case the workgroup is "divided" to wavefronts .Each wavefront indeed should have the number of workitems , which is equal to the number of processing elements (PE) of compute unit (CU).Thus the workgroup of size n,will be executed in

> ceil(n/wavefront_size)

Comment: Hasn't this been addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055195/why-is-there-a-cl-device-max-work-group-size